# Is there a Python package hat allows to perform a Kolmogorov Smirnov test against the Newcomb-Benford distribution that I can install via conda?

Tags: python, r, package, benfords-law

I found this package for R: https://rdrr.io/cran/BenfordTests/man/ks.benftest.html

It allows you to perform a Kolmogorov Smirnov test against the Benford distribution (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Benford%27s_law) given a list of numbers.

I am looking for the equivalent in Python (preferrably, I could install it via conda) but my Google searches were so far in vain. Any input appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend checking out this link: https://github.com/nyoshimizu/benfordspy. It's not downloadable via Conda, but you can install it directly from GitHub.

Comment: Thank you, looks like this is what I was looking for! Looks like the package hasn't been published in a scientific paper like the one for R, but I can work with it for now. Cheers!